# Laravel form request changing all hidden inputs on postback

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

I have the following 2 forms on a single page:

```
 {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AccountController@update']]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('action', 'personal-details') !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name', ['class' => 'h4']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        {!! errors_for('name', $errors) !!}
    </div>
    <div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update personal details</button>
    </div >
{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['AccountController@update']]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('action', 'email') !!}
    <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('new_email', 'New email address') !!}
         {!! Form::email('new_email', Input::old('new_email'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
         {!! errors_for('new_email', $errors) !!}
    </div>
    <div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update email address</button>
    </div >
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is my form request to handle validation:

```
class AccountRequest extends Request
{
    protected $action;

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];
        $this->action = $this->input('action');

        if ($this->action == 'personal-details') {
            $rules['name'] = 'required|max:255';
        }

        if ($this->action == 'email') {
           $rules['new_email'] = 'required|confirmed|email|max:255|unique:users,email';
        }


        return $rules;
    }


    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
        }

        return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl() . '#'. $this->action)
            ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
            ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
    }

}
```

If there is a validation error, upon postback the hidden fields on both forms are being set to what the hidden field value was on the orginal posted form. E.g. if I submit the personal-details form, on postback, the value of the the action field on both forms is being set to `personal-details`. If I submit the email form, upon post back the hidden field on both forms is being set to `email`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it so that upon postback the hidden field value doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by adding the following to beginning of the response method:

`$this->dontFlash[] = 'action';`